# What kind of array or list should I use to complete my randomization code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, random

```
    button.setOnClickListener {
        //???
        val rand = Random().nextInt()
        phrase.text=rand.toString()}
```

This is my code so far, but I can't seem to find an array that fits, or listOf, it always seems to end up with an error, is there something wrong with the code? My goal here is to write a couple of phrases that will be chosen randomly once the button is clicked.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow :D. A tip for you: if a question is correctly responded and you are satisfied with it, you can click on the check icon on the left side of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use something like that:

```
val random = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
val list : List<String> = (1..10).map {
    random.toString()
}

// now you can set the list of strings to whatever you want
// if you have an array of TextViews...

list.forEachIndexed { index, phrase ->
    phrasesTextViews[index].text = phrase
}
```

But if you want all the phrases in a single String:

```
phrasesTextView.text = (1..10).map { it.toString() }.joinToString(", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use listOf(), and then use random() on the list directly, without the need to create a random int:

```
val list = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four")
phrase.text = list.random()
```